# Rabbitmq get log info about acks

Tags: rabbitmq

My process is sending acks to RabbitMQ and they aren't getting recognized.  How do I configure RabbitMQ to log every ack it receives?

```
$ cat /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf
log.file.level = debug
log.connection.level = debug
log.channel.level = debug
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [tracing plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/firehose.html) may show the information you need. Otherwise, use Wireshark to examine the TCP packets. The AMQP protocol analyzer makes it easy to see the flow of messages.

You may not be including the correct delivery tag in your ack, just a thought - https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html#consumer-acknowledgements